# When launching the application, no content is displayed

Tags: android

I followed a tutorial to create an application that displays data from a mysql table, if i run the app everything works without error, the application opens with the header but without content, blank page instead of the content list.

activity_main.xml :

```js
    package com.example.bingmada

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONArray

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var adapter:ArticleAdapter ?=null
    var articles:ArrayList<Article> ?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        articles= ArrayList()
        getArticlesFromServer()
        adapter = ArticleAdapter(articles!!)

        var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclevirtuel)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerView.adapter=adapter
    }

    fun getArticlesFromServer(){
        var url="https://www.exemplesite.com/android/bingmada.php"
        var stringRequest=StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,Response.Listener { response -> parseData(response) }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this,"Erreur de connexion ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
        var req=Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        req.add(stringRequest)
    }

    fun parseData(response:String){
        var arrayJson = JSONArray(response)
        for(i in 0..arrayJson.length()-1){
            var currentObject=arrayJson.getJSONObject(i)
            var article = Article(currentObject.getInt("id"),
                currentObject.getString("nom"),
                currentObject.getString("lienimg"),
                currentObject.getString("ifram"))
            articles?.add(article)
        }
    }
}
```

the page https://www.exemplesite.com/android/bingmada.php show :

```html
[{"id":"1","nom":"tesmon","lienimg":"bingo1","ifram":"car1"},{"id":"2","nom":"testeds","lienimg":"bingo","ifram":"car2"},{"id":"3","nom":"test1","lienimg":"bingo3","ifram":"car3"},{"id":"4","nom":"testr","lienimg":"bingo4","ifram":"car4"},{"id":"5","nom":"test2","lienimg":"bingo5","ifram":"car5"},{"id":"6","nom":"letest","lienimg":"bingo6","ifram":"car6"},{"id":"7","nom":"test3","lienimg":"bingo7","ifram":"car7"},{"id":"8","nom":"testo","lienimg":"bingo8","ifram":"car8"},{"id":"9","nom":"test4","lienimg":"bingo9","ifram":"car9"},{"id":"10","nom":"testad","lienimg":"bingo10","ifram":"car10"},{"id":"11","nom":"test5","lienimg":"bingo11","ifram":"car11"},{"id":"12","nom":"testd","lienimg":"bingo12","ifram":"car12"},{"id":"13","nom":"test6","lienimg":"bingo13","ifram":"car13"},{"id":"14","nom":"testiu","lienimg":"bingo14","ifram":"car14"},{"id":"15","nom":"teste","lienimg":"bingo15","ifram":"car15"}]
```

in my page listevirtuelles.kt :

```js
package com.example.bingmada

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class Article(var id:Int,var nom:String,var lienimg:String, var ifram:String){

}

class ArticleAdapter (var articles:ArrayList<Article>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var vue=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_listevirtuelles, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(vue)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        holder.idvirtuelleli.setText(article.id)
        holder.nomvisite.setText(article.nom)
        holder.lieimgvisite.setText(article.lienimg)
        holder.ifram.setText(article.ifram)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(var vue:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vue){
        var idvirtuelleli=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.idvirtuelleli)
        var nomvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nom_virtuelleli)
        var lieimgvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lienimg)
        var ifram=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ifram)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml page :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclevirtuel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

a page activity_listevirtuelles.xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idvirtuelleli"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="id"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nom_virtuelleli"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lenom"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lienimg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="lien dimage"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ifram"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="codeifram"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />



</LinearLayout>
```

can you help me find the problem please?

Comment: I think, you forgot to notify adapter what data is there at the end of `parseData(..)` method. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the relevant data in the activity. Since it is an asynchronous process, can you apply the structure I added to connect the data with recyclerview?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var adapter:ArticleAdapter ?=null
    var articles:ArrayList<Article> ?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        articles= ArrayList()
        adapter = ArticleAdapter(articles!!) // 1 line up to changed
        getArticlesFromServer()
        
        var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclevirtuel)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerView.adapter=adapter
    }

    fun getArticlesFromServer(){
        var url="https://www.exemplesite.com/android/bingmada.php"
        var stringRequest=StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,Response.Listener { response -> parseData(response) }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this,"Erreur de connexion ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
        var req=Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        req.add(stringRequest)
        
    }

    fun parseData(response:String){
        var arrayJson = JSONArray(response)
        for(i in 0..arrayJson.length()-1){
            var currentObject=arrayJson.getJSONObject(i)
            var article = Article(currentObject.getInt("id"),
                currentObject.getString("nom"),
                currentObject.getString("lienimg"),
                currentObject.getString("ifram"))
            articles?.add(article)
        }
        adapter.notifydatasetchanged() // added
    }
}
```

Comment: not working :( i have this error : MainActivity.kt: (52, 16): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type ArticleAdapter?